# Fancybox перестал не работает

Tags: javascript, html, css

На сайте есть миниатюрные обрезанные изображения.

С помощью Fancybox их открывал в виде lightbox-а и имел возможность их закрыть.

При переносе сайта на сервер, возможность открывать(увеличивать) изображения в том же окне утратилась.  Вместо этого изображение открывается во вкладке т.к. путь указан через ссылку.

```html
<div class="equip" style="background-image: url('equip/helmet.svg')">
    <a href="image/2.png" data-fancybox>
        <img src="image/2.png" alt="" id='image' class='equip-item'>
    </a>
</div>
```

Помимо Fancybox пробовал и другие решения (`Magnific Popup`, `jQuery Lightbox`,  `iLightBox`), но результат не менялся.

Comment: Путь к скрипту неверный. Научись сначала в консоль смотреть, а потом вопросы задавать.

Comment: Благодарю за уточнение. Консоль проверил, ошибок нет, путь верный.

Comment: Других идей нет.

Comment: Если путь к скрипту верный, но не проходит привязка скрипта к элементу, то скорее всего проблема в инициализации. Если, к примеру, инициализация происходит через вызов функции ```$(document).ready()```, то ошибка в любом таком вызове приводит к тому, что все последующие не срабатывают.